# How do I create a footer that scrolls into view when page reaches the end

Tags: jquery, css, footer, parallax

I am trying to create a footer that scrolls up into view overlapping the page content when you reach the bottom of the page.  It's sort of like the opposite of this [Codepen by devkick](http://codepen.io/devkick/pen/Eaufm)

My site is currently this way but the designer asked for the new version to work as described above.  Basically the page stops scrolling and the footer scrolls into view overlapping the page.  I found tons of stuff on animating it but I want it to just be scrollable and simple with no jquery animations.  I looked at parallax effects too but all of them seem to be the same hidden footer that is revealed by the page being out of the way.

Here is my current footer setup

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="innerWrapper">
  <!--all the content!-->
</div>
</div>
    <footer>
        <div class="innerFooter">
            <!--all the content!-->
        </div>
    </footer>
```

and some of my footer css

```
//wrapper for everything but footer
.wrapper {
    position:relative;
    z-index:3;
    background-color: #fff;

}

//wrapper for internal content
.innerWrapper {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100vw;
}
footer {
  height: 380px;
  color:$white;
  font-size:12px;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
  background-color:$black;
}

footer .innerFooter {
  position: fixed;
  left: 1%;
  right: 1%;
  bottom: 1em;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Is jQuery acceptable to use here? You have it tagged, but your question says you don't want it. I seriously doubt it's possible without JS.

Comment: jQuery is free game here, but I don't want it to animate in.  But I may have to if there is no other option.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I'm not sure if what I initially wanted would be possible the way I was initially thinking.  I ended up taking the animation approach but the way it plays out it doesn't feel like an animation as much as I thought it would.

```
var homePage = $('.homeWrap').length;

$(window).scroll(function(){
  if (homePage === 0) {
    var footerHeight = $('footer').height();

  if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height() - 0)
    {
        if($('footer').data('size') == 'hide')
        {
            $('footer').data('size','show');
            $('footer').css('visibility', 'visible');
            $('footer').stop().animate({
                bottom:'0px'
            },400);
        }
    } 
    else
    {
        if($('footer').data('size') == 'show')
        {
            $('footer').data('size','hide');
            $('footer').stop().animate({
                bottom: '-'+footerHeight
            },400);

        }  
    }
  } else {}

});

$(document).ready(function() {
  if (homePage === 0) {
    var body = document.body,
    html = document.documentElement;
    $('footer').data('size','show');
    if ($('.innerWrapper').offsetHeight >= html.offsetHeight)
    {
        $('footer').data('size','hide');
    }
    else
    {
        $('footer').data('size','show');
        $('footer').stop().animate({
                bottom:'0px',
                visibility: 'visible'
            },400, function() {

            });
    }
  } else {}

});
```

feedback welcome!